# Как избежать пересоздания экрана, используя Navigation Components в Android?

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-view

У меня был BottomNavigationView с 5-ю фрагментами, я их переключал с помощью hide\show, так я мог сохранить состояние фрагмента при переключении. Решил подключить Navigation Components, фрагменты при переключении каждый раз создаются заново. Можно ли как-то избежать этого?